# List slicing with negative step size

Tags: python

Why does the below code returns an empty list when it should return `[4,  3,  2]` (because of the negative step size):

```
i = [  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
   #[  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
   #[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]
s = i[2:-5:-1]
print(s)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Understanding Python's slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-pythons-slice-notation)

Comment: I corrected my question, -1 should return the list in reverse order but its not happening.

Comment: Slices are `start:end`, so if `start` comes before `end` with a negative step, the result will be empty. `[-4:1:-1]` should do what you want.

Comment: @internet_user no, it does not work

Answer (score 4):

It starts counting from "2" going backwards (step -1) until "-5" is reached - but reaching the element "-5" would require positive step in this case.

For example the output of:

```
i[2::-1]
```

is:
`[2, 1, 0]`

Comment: How can I get the output of [4,  3,  2] ?

Comment: Something like: i[4:1:-1]

Comment: Thanks, it works. Can you please add a small explanation of how it works.

Comment: i[1:4] gives elements 1,2,3 (right limit is always not inclusive).

But negative step i[1:4:-1]: causes similar effect like getting i[4:1]

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, when going from left to right (using negative or positive version of index), a positive step size is required.

Going from right to left requires a negative step size:

```
i = [  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
   #[  0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9]
   #[-10, -9, -8, -7, -6, -5, -4, -3, -2, -1]

# to get 6, 7, 8
print(i[6:9])
print(i[-4:-1:1])
print(i[6:-1:1])
print(i[-4:9:1])


# to get 8, 7, 6
print(i[8:5:-1])
print(i[-2:-5:-1])
print(i[-2:5:-1])
print(i[8:-5:-1])
```